# DataGrid Width has no affect in Windows Mobile. C#

Tags: c#, windows-mobile

I a beginner in Windows Mobile development and found that when I set the Width using a DataGridTextBoxColumn it does not affect the DataGrid column size.
Here is my code:

```
        DataGridTableStyle tableStyle = new DataGridTableStyle();
        tableStyle.MappingName = "MainStyle";

        DataGridTextBoxColumn tbcName = new DataGridTextBoxColumn();
        tbcName.Width = 120;
        tbcName.MappingName = "Name";
        tbcName.HeaderText = "Name";
        tableStyle.GridColumnStyles.Add(tbcName);

        DataGridTextBoxColumn tbcValue = new DataGridTextBoxColumn();
        tbcValue.Width = 200;
        tbcValue.MappingName = "Value";
        tbcValue.HeaderText = "Value";
        tableStyle.GridColumnStyles.Add(tbcValue);

        // dgUserAttributes is defined as a System.Windows.Forms.DataGrid
        dgUserAttributes.TableStyles.Clear();
        dgUserAttributes.TableStyles.Add(tableStyle);
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

As [Henk Holterman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/60761/henk-holterman) stated you must map the **DataGridTableStyle** to the name of the **DataTable** bound to the the **DataGrid**. As an alternative, you can set the *MappingName* of each **DataGridTextBoxColumn** to the column name of the **DataColumn** in the bound **DataTable**.

Assuming you have added a **DataGrid** named *dgUserAttributes* to a **Form** named *Form1* in the form designer, you can test how the **DataGridTextBoxColumn** *width* property changes the width of the column in the displayed **DataGrid** using the code below.

Also check that you have not set a value to **dgUserAttributes** *TableStyles* collection at design time that could be overriding the values you have set programatically.

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        //Create In-Memory DataTable
        DataTable myTable = new DataTable();

        // Add DataColumns to the DataTable.
        DataColumn myNameColumn = new DataColumn("Name");
        myNameColumn.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.String");
        myNameColumn.DefaultValue = "default string";
        myTable.Columns.Add(myNameColumn);
        DataColumn myValueColumn = new DataColumn("Value");
        myValueColumn.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.String");
        myValueColumn.DefaultValue = "default string";
        myTable.Columns.Add(myValueColumn);

        //Bind DataTable to dataGrid1
        dgUserAttributes.DataSource = myTable;

        DataGridTableStyle tableStyle = new DataGridTableStyle();
        //tableStyle.MappingName = "MainStyle";
        DataGridTextBoxColumn tbcName = new DataGridTextBoxColumn();
        tbcName.Width = 12; 
        tbcName.MappingName = "Name";
        tbcName.HeaderText = "Name";
        tableStyle.GridColumnStyles.Add(tbcName);
        DataGridTextBoxColumn tbcValue = new DataGridTextBoxColumn();
        tbcValue.Width = 300;
        tbcValue.MappingName = "Value";
        tbcValue.HeaderText = "Value";
        tableStyle.GridColumnStyles.Add(tbcValue);
        // dgUserAttributes is defined as a System.Windows.Forms.DataGrid
        dgUserAttributes.TableStyles.Clear();        
        dgUserAttributes.TableStyles.Add(tableStyle);           
    }
```

Comment: In your example if there were 10 columns would you have to add 10 columns or just the ones that you are concerned with?